# How to pass variable from a parent window to Brightcove player HTML?

Tags: brightcove

This is the example code that I have on my page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

  <script src="https://www.netapp.com/us/static/js/jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>
  <body>
    <p>
<button class="bcls-button" onclick="playVideo()">Play Video</button>
<button class="bcls-button" onclick="pauseVideo()">Pause Video</button>
</p>
<div class="n-container">
            <div class="n-row">
                <div class="n-col-md-12">

<h2>Advanced (non-iFrame):</strong></h2>

<iframe src="//players.brightcove.net/260701648001/FcmqUildl_default/index.html?videoId=5448507890001" allowfullscreen="" webkitallowfullscreen="" mozallowfullscreen="" style="width: 640px; height: 360px;"></iframe>
</div></div></div>
<script>

var cid = "12345";
var theProtocol = location.protocol,
theURL = theProtocol + "//players.brightcove.net",
// Get a reference to the iframe element
iframeTag = document.querySelector("iframe"),    
// Retrieve window object needed for postMessage
win = iframeTag.contentWindow;
console.log('theURL:', theURL);
console.log('win:', win);

function playVideo() {
// Post message passing 'playVideo' as the data
win.postMessage(cid, theURL);
}

function pauseVideo() {
// Post message passing 'pauseVideo' as the data
win.postMessage("pauseVideo", theURL);
}

</script>

  </body>
</html>
```

The plugin code is added in the Brightcove player as per this reference https://support.brightcove.com/brightcove-player-sample-playpause-video-iframe-parent

```
videojs.registerPlugin('listenForParent', function() {
var myPlayer = this;
// This method called when postMessage sends data into the iframe
function controlVideo(evt){
console.log("evt.data" + evt.data)
};
// Listen for the message, then call controlVideo() method when received
window.addEventListener("message",controlVideo);
});
```

This works fine when i click on the PlayVideo. I need to make this work on load. If i call the function PlayVideo on document ready it gives error saying  Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('http://players.brightcove.net') does not match the recipient window's origin ('http://localhost').

Any idea?

Comment: You’ll presumably have to wait until the plugin initialization is done, or at least until the iframe content is done loading.

Comment: Thanks. it worked. I have been struggling with this so long. I added that on window load and it worked. Thanks again